# How to add 'drawtext' to overlay in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

The command is `ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i "demo_1.jpg" -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x360[background];[background][0:v]overlay=shortest=1:x='min(-(t)*20,0)'" -qscale 1 -y out.mp4`

I am animating the image from right to left. In the above command, I need to add text, How to integrate the drawtext feature of ffmpeg to that.

The video animation is https://youtu.be/teXUiPKX83o.

Need to add text to that video.

Comment: Does the text move with the image?

Comment: @Mulvya No. I need to add text which will not move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i "demo_1.jpg" -filter_complex
   "nullsrc=size=640x360[background];
    [background][0:v]overlay=shortest=1:x='min(-(t)*20,0)',
    drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font':fontsize=30:fontcolor=yellow:x=50:y=50:text='Text'" 
 -qscale 1 -y out.mp4
```

See drawtext [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) for more info.

Comment: I made a mistake in separating the drawtext (I used semicolon and mentioning image as source).